# documentElement.clientHeight returns more than window height

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on an existing web app using jQuery 3.0.0.
`<!DOCTYPE html>` exists and the page scrolls to the bottom.
But both `$(document).height()` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` return 1300
But https://bestfirms.com/what-is-my-screen-resolution/ returns 1536 x 864
So how can I get exact height of the window and not the entire document ?

Comment: Are you looking for window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight?

Comment: Thank You. That worked. But I am surprised that `$(window).height()` is also returning 1300

Comment: what-is-my-screen-resolution is returning `screen.height`, that's not the same as window unless your fullscreen mode & don't have any zoom..

Comment: Oh, Ok, I actually just wanted to know the current laptop's screen height in a new window and wanted to cross-check with the web app's `$(window).height()` which was no where near